# Computed Observable not updating

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have two primary problems. First, the parentheses I have on line 16 is causing an error. Second, and more importantly, even when I delete out that line, the data binding is not updating for the computed property. Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/austinfacts/Lxpgu/1/ 
Or just the code if you prefer.

```
<form>
                        <p>
                            Known Volume: <input id="boyle1_volume1_text" data-bind="value: volume1_text" type="text" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            In: <select id="boyle1_volume1_select" data-bind="value: volume1_select">
                                    <option value="0">- Select -</option>
                                    <option value="1">Liters</option>
                                    <option value=".001">Milliliters</option>
                            </select>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Pressure Corresponding to Known Volume: <input id="boyle1_pressure1_text" data-bind="value: pressure1_text" type="text" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            In: <select id="boyle1_pressure1_select" data-bind="value: pressure1_select">
                                <option value="0">- Select -</option>
                                <option value="101.3">Atmospheres</option>
                                <option value="1">Kilopascals</option>
                            </select>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Known Pressure Corresponding to Unknown Volume: <input id="boyle1_pressure2_text" data-bind="value: pressure2_text" type="text" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            In: <select id="boyle1_pressure2_select" data-bind="value: pressure2_select">
                                <option value="0">- Select -</option>
                                <option value="101.3">Atmospheres</option>
                                <option value="1">Kilopascals</option>
                            </select>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Answer In: <select id="boyle1_volume2_select" data-bind="value: volume2_select">
                                    <option value="0">- Select -</option>
                                    <option value="1">Liters</option>
                                    <option value="1000">Milliliters</option>
                            </select>
                        </p>
                        <span id="boyle1_volume_result" data-bind="text: answer1"></span>
```

```
var boyle1 = {
volume1_text: ko.observable(parseInt(0)),
volume1_select: ko.observable(parseInt(0)),

pressure1_text: ko.observable(parseInt(0)),
pressure1_select: ko.observable(parseInt(0)),

pressure2_text: ko.observable(parseInt(0)),
pressure2_select: ko.observable(parseInt(0)),

volume2_select: ko.observable(parseInt(0)),
};
boyle1.answer1 = ko.computed(function () {
    return this.volume1_text() * this.volume1_select() 
    * this.pressure1_text() * this.pressure1_select()
    / ( this.pressure2_text() * pressure2_select() )
    * this.volume2_select();
}, boyle1);
ko.applyBindings(boyle1);
```

What am I doing wrong? Any input would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a 'this.' in front of pressure2_select. Here is the fixed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxpgu/3/)

```
    var boyle1 = {
        volume1_text: ko.observable(parseInt(0)),
        volume1_select: ko.observable(parseInt(0)),

        pressure1_text: ko.observable(parseInt(0)),
        pressure1_select: ko.observable(parseInt(0)),

        pressure2_text: ko.observable(parseInt(0)),
        pressure2_select: ko.observable(parseInt(0)),

        volume2_select: ko.observable(parseInt(0)),
    };

    boyle1.answer1 = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.volume1_text() * this.volume1_select() 
        * this.pressure1_text() * this.pressure1_select()
        / ( this.pressure2_text() * this.pressure2_select() )
        * this.volume2_select();
    }, boyle1);

    ko.applyBindings(boyle1);
```

Comment: Thank you. I struggle way too long on stupid things like that.